# tomcat simple redirection

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I have a page that's accessible like this

```
   http://site/foo.html
```

Is it possible to make is available at

```
   http://site/foo
```

just changing the configuration in web.xml?

I'm migrating an application and the second url is bookmarked and linked in several places.

Comment: I'm sure there is a correct answer to this, but in case you do not get other answers, you could create a folder `foo` with the index file redirecting to `foo.html`

Comment: @MadsNielsen I ended up using your solution. Per BalusC's answer, I could create a new filter but I didn't want to add anything more to the codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is it possible to make ... just changing the configuration in web.xml?*

No. You need to  either homegrow a simple [`Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) for this which transparently forwards the incoming requests based on their [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) to the desired resources by [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29), or to use a 3rd party one such as [Tuckey's URL rewrite filter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) which is much similar to the well known Apache HTTPD's `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: This `Tuckey's URL rewriter` can you use it so that a url like `http://ip:8080/someProject/` is mapped/accepted by a war under Tomcat named `anotherProject`?